# MKLocalSearch WITHOUT MKMapView

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mklocalsearch

I would like to use MKLocalSearch to display results for a pre-defined string with results relevant to the users position, however all the examples I have seen so far require or use MKMapView to set the users location, and perhaps use the search bar to gather the text needed for the search.

I would simply like to perform the search on a predefined string and load the results in a tableview, without first having a map, is there a good example of how to do this?

Editing to add more detail, including the code I am currently trying to use.  This code does not produce a table of results.

Further edit:  Anna below has pointed out that the problem might be in UISearchDisplayController, however I have ripped the current code straight out of a working example project, so I really can't see where things are going wrong or why UISearchDisplayController is not showing the results.

header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CallACabViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    MKLocalSearch *localSearch;
    MKLocalSearchResponse *results;
}

-(IBAction)closeButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - LocationUpdating

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2];
    } else {
        oldLocation = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
    MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.00, 1500.00);
    [self performSearch:userLocation];

}

#pragma mark - Search Methods


-(void)performSearch:(MKCoordinateRegion)aRegion
{
    // Cancel any previous searches.
    [localSearch cancel];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Perform a new search.
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"taxi";
    request.region = aRegion;

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        if (error != nil) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Map Error",nil)
                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            return;
        }

        if ([response.mapItems count] == 0) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No Results",nil)
                                        message:nil
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            return;
        }

        results = response;

        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    }];

    NSLog(@"DEBUG");


}


#pragma mark - TableView Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [results.mapItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *IDENTIFIER = @"SearchResultsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:IDENTIFIER];
    }

    MKMapItem *item = results.mapItems[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)closeButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: MKLocalSearch does not require a map at all.  Just give it a string and use the results however you like.

Comment: Does it show one of the alert views ("error" or "no results")?  If `response` contains items but the search table view is empty, the issue may be with UISearchDisplayController and not MKLocalSearch.  Again, a map is not needed but there may really not be any results in the region you request.

Comment: No, it never shows the UIAlerts, if I perform the search on a timer, I can see that the results instance is not nil, and has mapItems which could be displayed so I would agree with your assessment that it is a problem with UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: Maybe the UISearchDisplayController is hiding the table view for some reason.  You don't have to use a UISearchDisplayController though.  Also, you can just put a NSLog(@"response = %@", response); directly in the search completion handler block to check the response (don't need a timer).

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in end the end, but without using the provided search table.  I stored the response results and then implemented my own UITableView, assigning each result to a cell.